# Performance analysis over multiple executions

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to do a performance analysis of a program using the /usr/bin/time command over multiple executions. When I run it, a couple of the executions take a long time as compared to the others.

This is my program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define OUTPUTNAME "fprint.out"
main()
{
    long i;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s.  Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME);
            exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<400000; i++) {  /* write 400,000 Xs with fprintf */
            if (fprintf(fp,"X") < 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

and this is part of my output:

```
real 0.03
user 0.00
sys 0.03

real 0.33
user 0.00
sys 0.02

real 0.02
user 0.00
sys 0.02
```

Any idea why this is happening? I'm guessing this is caused by something not related to the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed right. "Real" time is also sometimes called wall time, the time taken as if you were watching a clock on the wall (a very accurate one in this particular case).

If, for example, your process is switched out for ten minutes while the system does something else more important, the wall time will be ten minutes more than (you think) it should be:

```
real 10m0.33 user 0.00 sys 0.02
```

If you want to measure CPU usage by your process, just add together `sys` and `user`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running this on a remote PC, so I guess it's because of some system process running there.

Comment: + @npn: Yes, you should expect much variation, but don't put too much stock in "CPU time" because this program is IO-bound. Unless you have it print to a null device, the `fprintf(fp` will be taking between 90% and 100% of the total time.